# Searching for string in char array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, search, char

```
char names [MAX_CLASS_SIZE][MAX_NAME_SIZE+1]={"Julias Hoffman","Dianne Conner","Mitchell Cooper","Johnnie Greene","Johanna Mason","Kevin Adkins","Brandi Spencer","Marian Tyler","Chester Cross","Martin Lawrence","Jane Smith","Sara Jones"};

char specificName[]="";

int search(char names[][MAX_NAME_SIZE+1],char specificName[])

for(i=0;i<MAX_CLASS_SIZE;i++){
    if (strcmp(names[i],specificName)==0)
    {
        printf("Found %s",names[i]);
        return i;
    }
}
```

This function receives an array of strings, called name and an array of characters that represents a specific name. This function searches through the array name for the specific name and returns the index of the specific name if it is found, -1 if it is not found.

In `main()` I ask the user for a name and store it in the `specificName` char array using `scanf("%s",specificName);`. Then in the `search()` function I am attempting to search the array of names for the user given name and return a certain value based on if the name is found. I have included the necessary libraries. I am trying to do this using `strcmp`, but `search()` doesn't find the matching name.

Comment: Please explain, *but it does not seem to work properly*. What error are you getting? Or what unexpected results?

Comment: And how do you store input into the `specificName`?

Comment: sorry for not being clear.  The function does not find the matching name.  I am storing input using scanf("%s",specificName);

Comment: @MichaelSciortino Please check my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int search(char **names,char *specificName, size_t length){
    size_t i,found=0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        if (strcmp(*(names + i),specificName)==0){
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    return found == 1 ? 0 : 1;
}


int main(void) {
    size_t length;
    char specificName[100];
    char *names[12]={"Julias Hoffman","Dianne Conner","Mitchell Cooper","Johnnie Greene",
                     "Johanna Mason","Kevin Adkins","Brandi Spencer","Marian Tyler",
                     "Chester Cross","Martin Lawrence","Jane Smith","Sara Jones"};

    length = sizeof names / sizeof *(names + 0);

    printf("Type a name to be searched:> ");
    if( fgets (specificName, 100, stdin) == NULL){
        printf("Error!\n");
    }

    specificName[strcspn(specificName, "\n")] = 0;

    if((search(names,specificName,length)) == 0){
        printf("Found %s",specificName);
    }else{
        printf("There was no Record Found.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Type a name to be searched:> Sara Jones
Found Sara Jones
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This approach has worked and i believe that I realized that it was the way i was storing input that was giving me the unexpected output.

Comment: How would i go about storing the input so that it stores both first and last name? As it is necessary i ask the user for the input.

Comment: @MichaelSciortino :) Just  a Moment.

Comment: @MichaelSciortino Please see my Answer now. The problem is that fgets stores the `'\n'` (newLine character) and there you need a function like `strcspn` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Took a quick look and it seems to work fine. Your i needs to be declared as an int but otherwise, the following works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CLASS_SIZE 100
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 100

int strcmp(const char *, const char *);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char names [MAX_CLASS_SIZE][MAX_NAME_SIZE+1]={"Julias Hoffman","Dianne Conner","Mitchell Cooper","Johnnie Greene","Johanna Mason","Kevin Adkins","Brandi Spencer","Marian Tyler","Chester Cross","Martin Lawrence","Jane Smith","Sara Jones"};
    char specificName[]="Brandi Spencer";
    int search(char names[][MAX_NAME_SIZE+1],char specificName[]);
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_CLASS_SIZE;i++){
        if (strcmp(names[i],specificName)==0){
            printf("Found %s",names[i]);
            return i;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

Found Brandi Spencer

My guess would be is that you are not passing the user input correctly. Check specificName[] prior to strcmp().

Comment: Thank you Alexander, much appreciated.

Comment: You were right about the input not being passed correctly.

Comment: How would i go about storing the input so that it stores both first and last name? As it is necessary i ask the user for the input.

Comment: You can use the strtok() function to split a string (and specify the delimiter to use i.e. " ") http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok  If you want to scale it out a bit I'd probably want to use something like a dictionary as storage and/or implement a linked-list (makes it easier to delete). Hope this helps.